# Android foreground service won't stop

Tags: android, android-gps, foreground-service

I've finally set up my app (tracking live GPS) to track using a foreground service. However the issue I'm running into now, is the service never stops, even after I tell it to. I keep getting logs whenever I get a new location from the location client. I can't seem to find anything that explains this anywhere, so any help would be appreciated.

Service's first few relevant methods look like this...

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    String channelId = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O ? createNotificationChannel(notificationManager) : "";
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId);
    Notification notification = notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setPriority(PRIORITY_MIN)
            .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
            .build();

    startForeground(ID_SERVICE, notification);
}

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
private String createNotificationChannel(NotificationManager notificationManager){
    String channelId = "my_service_channelid";
    String channelName = "My Foreground Service";
    NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
    // omitted the LED color
    channel.setImportance(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE);
    channel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    return channelId;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION)) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received Start Foreground Intent");
        mLocationClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

        mLocationRequest.setInterval(LOCATION_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_LOCATION_INTERVAL);

        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        mLocationClient.connect();
    } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.STOPFOREGROUND_ACTION)) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received Stop Foreground Intent");
        mLocationClient.disconnect();
        mLocationClient.unregisterConnectionCallbacks(this);
        stopForeground(true);
        stopSelf();
    }
    //Make it stick to the notification panel so it is less prone to get cancelled by the Operating System.
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

`mLocationRequest` is a `com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest`

`mLocationClient` is a `com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient`

Activity starts it like so:
`ContextCompat.startForegroundService(this, buildLocationServiceIntent(true));`

And *attempts* to stop it like this:
`ContextCompat.startForegroundService(this, buildLocationServiceIntent(false));`
This line is in the `onDestroy` method on the activity if that matters.

The `Log.i`'s you see appear in my app log exactly when you'd expect them to. But the logs from my `onLocationChanged` method keep coming indefinitely after 'stopping' the service. I'm sure I'm missing something simple, I'm just not seeing it.

**Edit**

Service code -> https://codeshare.io/5D7LvZ
Activity code -> https://codeshare.io/5g4nO8

**Edit v2**

Here's my app.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "[[appid]]"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

ext {
    androidSupportVersion = "27.1.1"
    playServicesVersion = "15.0.1"
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${androidSupportVersion}"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:${androidSupportVersion}"
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:6.0.7') {
        transitive = true
    }
    //required support lib modules
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${androidSupportVersion}"
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${androidSupportVersion}"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-annotations:${androidSupportVersion}"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:${androidSupportVersion}"

    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:${playServicesVersion}"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:${playServicesVersion}"

    implementation 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0.1'

    implementation "com.mikepenz:iconics-core:3.0.4@aar"
    implementation "com.mikepenz:iconics-views:3.0.4@aar"
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:google-material-typeface:3.0.1.2.original@aar'
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:material-design-iconic-typeface:2.2.0.4@aar'
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:fontawesome-typeface:5.0.13.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `Context.stopService()` and just handle all your destroys and such in the Service's `onDestroy()`?

Comment: @TheWanderer I don't have a `Context.stopService()`, but there's a `stopService(Intent)` I have access to in the activity. Is that what you mean? If so, I've already tried that, But I'll give it another go, just in case.

Comment: @TheWanderer Yep, same result.

Comment: Where do you send intent with action to stop foreground? Have you tried placing debug point at `stopSelf()` line. Check if app even goes to that line.

Comment: @AadityaBrahmbhatt I'll give that a go as soon as I have opportunity to, but I think I've already done that. There's certainly no exceptions being thrown, so there's that.

Answer (score 0):

Stopping a service explicitly wouldn't terminate the service as long as there are bound components, and te unbinding all components process wouldn't terminate it until it’s explicitly stopped (if it was ever started). Also note that no matter how many times you call te metod startService(), a single call to stopService() or stopSelf() will stop it.I think this concept will help you to solve your issue.

Edit:
As I do not have enough reputation I am unable to comment.Therefor I am editing my answer.

If you do allow your service to be started and bound, then when the service has been started, the system does not destroy the service when all clients unbind. Instead, you must explicitly stop the service by calling stopSelf() or stopService().Then the service will stop.

This link may help you,

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services

Comment: If there are bound components and I call stopService() or stopService(), then what happed?

Comment: @Sana I am explicitly calling `stopService` and `stopSelf`. If you check out the `onStartCommand` in my question, I've got `stopSelf()` in there on the `stop` condition. I've also tried calling `stopSelf()` in `onDestroy()` and it gets hit, but the events keep firing. Later today I'll edit my question with the entire activity, and service, so hopefully that'll provide a little more useful context.

Comment: I will look for your edited answer.I will try on that in android studio.

Comment: Please also send the app.gradle file.It will save my time :)

Comment: @Sana I've once again  updated the question with your requested app.gradle file.